# MongoDB: Query by size of array with a filtered value

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, I have a collection ("users") with the following basic schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("50e5de00b623143995c5b739")
    "name" : "Jon",
    "emails_sent" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "invite",
            "sent_time" : ISODate("2013-04-21T21:11:50.999Z")
        },
        {
            "type" : "invite",
            "sent_time" : ISODate("2013-04-15T21:10:35.999Z")
        },
        {
            "type" : "follow",
            "sent_time" : ISODate("2013-04-21T21:11:50.999Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to query for users based on the $size of **emails_sent** of a certain "type" only, e.g. only count "invite" emails. Is there any way to achieve this sort of "filtered count" in a standard mongo query?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.users.aggregate([
 {$unwind:'$emails_sent'},
 {$match: {'$emails_sent.type':'invite'}},
 {$group : {_id : '$name', sumOfEmailsSent:{$sum:1} }}
]);
```

BTW you are missing a square bracket which closes the $emails_sent array.

Comment: and of course there would be another $match as the last step that would only return the users who had the desired number of emails of this type, right?

Comment: Yes of course. Maybe programmer wants a see an individual user or list of users with specific email_sent counts. It is left to programmers choice.